# How to create time series plot with a timestamp format: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have a decently sized table that I'm reading from a .csv file. I would like to create a time plot of the values.

```
file = 'test.csv'
names = ['id', 'siteid', 'machineid', 'tag', 'value', 'ts', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'min', 'max', 'avg', 'std']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(file)
dataset.columns = names
dataset.head(500)
for value in dataset.ts:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%b/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Here's an example entry

```
     id      siteid     machineid   tag                              value               ts     year    month   day     min     max     avg       std
18  5758593     NaN     NaN     ALineFillHopper.Level.LIT_325.PV    65.410011   3/9/2019 5:30   2019    3   9   64.466148   65.627884   64.823166   0.352118
```

I get this as an error

```
ValueError: time data '3/9/2019 4:00' does not match format '%b/%d/%Y %H:%M'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use: `'%m%d/%Y %H:%M'`

Comment: Ah yes that worked. Now I'm struggling to loop through the timestamps and plotting the values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have solved the problem with the data format and struggling to plot the "value" column against the "ts" column. If I have interpreted your problem wrong then I am sorry. To plot two columns in pandas dataframe (I hope you are using pandas dataframe) you can use the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
column1 = dataset['value']
column2 = dataset['ts']

df = {'value' : column1,
     'ts'    : column2}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.plot(style=['o','rx'])
```